# Regexp with flex

Tags: c++, c, regex, flex-lexer

I am trying to write a flex rule like this:

```
%%
[0-9]+                  yylval=atoi(yytext); return NUMBER;
[<]                     return LANGLE;
[/>]                    return CLOSERANGLE;
[>]                     return RANGLE;
[/]                     return SLASH;
[ a-zA-Z0-9]            yylval=strdup(yytext); return ANYTHING;
\n                      /* ignore end of line */;
[ \t]+                  /* ignore whitespace */;
%%
```

When i run a flex program against the file, it says:

```
example4.l:19: warning, rule cannot be matched
example4.l:20: warning, rule cannot be matched
```

I guess this is because in the rule `[/>]` it matches either `/` or `>` . But the question is how do i write that rule so that it matches `/` **and** `>` together?

I tried the documentation: It says that:

```
‘rs’
    the regular expression ‘r’ followed by the regular expression ‘s’; called concatenation
```

Am I not doing the same? What's wrong? And how to cope with this?

Comment: The double char string is written in regex without the class (square) brackets, `/>` If it requires brackets, then its this `[/][>]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess this is because in the rule [/>] it matches either / or > .

Exactly.

> But the question is how do i write that rule so that it matches / and > together?

```
"/>"
```

> Am I not doing the same?

No. `[/]` matches <kbd>/</kbd> and `[>]` matches <kbd>></kbd>. So `[/][>]` would work. But the quoted form is more normal.